# Including pictures with javascript or html

Tags: javascript, image

I am trying to include an image  in my HTML document which is actually no a problem at all.

However, I am also trying to provide my website to several users and according to whom is logged in, another image with a different src should be shown. All images are stored locally. Actually, the src always includes the user´s name e.g. src = "public/pictures/picture1User5.jpg

Using cookies I know who is looged in and could generate the src However, is there a way to change the src dynamicallly with JavaScript?

Comment: Add the code you have for generating the `src` from the cookie. It won't be too far a stretch to achieve what you want from that...

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I could write in JavaScript: var src = 'public/pictures/picture1' + document.cookie '.jpg'                                                                                                               But I cannot change the source in the html document...

Comment: You say: "Using cookies I know who is looged in and could generate the src", show us the code how you generate the `src` here and we can advise you further

Comment: I use following code to generate the src:                                                     var src = \'public/pictures/picture1\' + document.cookie + \'.jpg\'

Comment: `document.getElementById('#image-id').src = '/public/pictures/picture1' + document.cookie + '.jpg'`

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer!